Происхождение семантики 'сломаться, нарушиться' гл. 'полететь'
Гл. 'полететь' имеет семантику (в том числе) 'сломаться, нарушиться'.
Каково происхождение такой семантики?
Имеет ли семантика 'сломаться, нарушиться' гл. 'полететь' какое-либо отношение к семантическим сдвигам / метафорическим сдвигам значений?

Есть такое выражение Этот механизм полетел к чертям. Тут глагол полететь используется буквально, по своему прямому значению, без всяких сдвигов и метафор. Другое дело что само выражение метафорично, но глагол буквален.
